# Timers in a webpage are synchronous to times in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, timer, phantomjs

I have a problem concerning phantomjs and timers. It seems that timers in a web page are synchronous to the times in pahntomjs, as a result you can't create nice gif which will show  nice website animations (animations always use times).

Here is the code illustrating the problem:

`test.phantom.js`

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open("test.html", function(){
    var i = 0
    setInterval(function(){
            page.render('test-capture/'+i+'.gif', {format : "gif"});            
            i++;
            if(i == 20)
                    phantom.exit();
    }, 20);             
});
```

`test.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script>
var div;
window.onload = function(){
    div = document.getElementById("t");
    var times = 0;  
    setInterval(function(){
        div.innerHTML = "" + (++times);
    }, 1)
}
    </script>

    <body>          
    <div id="t">
    0
    </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see phantomjs triggers a render call every 20 milliseconds, while the webpage changes the content of `div#t` every millisecond. You may expect that in the resulting 20 images the content of `div#t` will change with a step of 20 but this is not happening. I don't have enough reputation to post images, but the content in `div#t` is changing with a step of 1 millisecond.

Is this a bug or it should happen like this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because javascript execution is single-threaded even if you have the page context and the outside context. The second thing is that rendering (gif) isn't cheap. On my machine it takes around 100 msec to render the gif on average. During that time, no javascript can be executed and time stands still.

So when you the rendering is complete, then both timers can continue to run. So the formula would be:

```
var pageContextAdvancement = Math.max(outsideIntervalDuration - timeToRender, 1);
```

So, no it's not possible to animate something with PhantomJS. It just isn't the right tool.

---

At least on my machine, the following seems to work, but this might change if the workload changes.

```
page.open("test.html", function(){
    var i = 0
    function run(){
        page.render('test/'+i+'.gif', {format : "gif"});
        i++;
        if(i == 20)
            phantom.exit();
        setTimeout(run, 200);
    }
    setTimeout(run, 170);
});
```